# Change image resolution but keep physical size

Tags: javascript, html, css

is there any possibility to change an image's resolution on clientside (using CSS, Javascript, whatever) but keep it's size on the screen?

Example: I want to dispaly a 1920x1080 image with a resolution of 20x10 at a size of 200x100. Just using a img element, set it's source and width/height to 20x10 surely works, but now I'd like to display the scaled image at a size of 200x100.

Is that somehow possible without generating a new image on server-side?

Comment: So the final image would look pixelated?

Comment: do you mean resampling and resize?

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369788/pure-javascript-image-handling-library-in-binary-form-not-through-dom it seems like there is client-side support in image manipulation already.

Comment: yes, the final image needs to look pixelated

Comment: Drawing the image inside a canvas and use it's data as new imagesource is a solution i already thought of. But first I guess it's so slow and of course using a canvas the browser need to support HTML5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using HTML5 canvas:

Given an original image of any size that you want to give a size of `200` x `200` and a resolution of `50` x `50`:

1. Make a canvas of `50` x `50`
2. Draw the image with arguments defining a width and height of `50`
3. Enlarge the canvas **through CSS** to stretch it to `200` x `200`.

Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/eGjak/234/.

As a side note, HTML5 canvas uses anti-aliasing in all browsers as far as I'm concerned, with no ability to turn that off. So instead of pixelated results you'll have blurry results.

```
// paint 200x200 image with resolution 50x50
var w = 200,
    h = 200,
    p = 50,
    q = 50;

var img = $("img").get(0);

img.onload = function() {
    cv.width = p;  // set canvas resolution
    cv.height = q;

    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, p, q); // draw image with given resolution

    cv.style.width = w + "px";  // enlarge canvas by stretching
    cv.style.height = h + "px";
};

img.src = "http://www.lorempixum.com/300/300/";
```

Comment: Drawing the image inside a canvas and use it's data as new imagesource is a solution i already thought of. But first I guess it's so slow and of course using a canvas the browser need to support HTML5

Comment: @user1039407: If you want to go for compatibility, you'd be best off doing it server-side. If you set the resolution low it won't be that slow since relatively few pixels have to be painted on the canvas (setting the width through CSS doesn't seem to be a performance hit).

Comment: But since the method needs to be called several times calculating the image severside will take way too long. Using the canvas and disable the feature on old browsers would be the best solution though.

But isn't there maybe any other possibility? For example display the image element with the size of 50² and somehow resize it's content without being "redrawn"?

Comment: @user1039407: I'm not sure - resizing means redrawing anyhow. In fact, going the canvas way doesn't require any manual resizing code - just alter the relevant CSS properties.

Comment: How do you mean that? "alter the relevant CSS properties"?

Comment: @user1039407: Changing `width`/`height` to resize the image. You don't need to do manual resizing through JavaScript for that part.

Comment: Ah, ok... but redrawing it with javascript is, of course, necessary. Since I thing it's the only client-side solution I'll mark it as answer - thank you :)