# Javascript: scale (re-size) jpeg with 100 quality in client browser

Tags: javascript, html, resize, jpeg

From Googling/SOing around it looks like browsers are not capable, but am looking for a way to resize (scale) images in client-side javascript with similar results to Gimp or ImageMagick, i.e no loss of "quality".

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you mean with sharp edges? That would be [`image-rendering`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering).

Comment: I was unaware you lost quality in an image when you resize it in the browser - could you elaborate further?

Comment: If you mean sharp edges (without antialiasing) then this is a dupe of [How to stretch images with no antialiasing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8597081/4642212) or [Disable antialising when scaling images](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14068103/4642212).

Comment: what quality are you talking about? the felt quality of an image, or the quality-settings when encoding?

Comment: @Thomas the "quality-settings" I believe. When I do a re-size in Gimp I get a quality option 0 - 100. I want to scale with "100" quality (whatever that really means)

Comment: @RichardH Just to cover these topics: you never scale with a quality-setting. the quality-setting is a parameter of the encoding-process for the JPEG-encoder. So if you get immediately an modal that asks you for the quality-setting this means, that immediately after the resizing, GIMP recodes the image, wich in my optinion is a bad thing, cause so you potentiate quality-loss; it should use the raw pixel-data until **you are finished and ask him** to encode (save) the result. But that's off topic. Although it leads me to the question: **what are actually you trying to build?**

Comment: Have you tried this solution?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/961913/image-resize-before-upload